# Como copio al portapapeles un icono que tengo en un textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo el siguiente código que me funciona correctamente la opcion de copiar al portapapeles, pero me gustaria tener la opcion de copiar en texto el icono que tengo dentro del textarea, es decir:

Dentro del `textarea` tenemos varias etiquetas `<p>` y junto con ellas una etiqueta con un icono (`<i>`) , en donde me copia correctamente lo de las etiquetas `<p>` pero quisiera de alguna forma que tambien me copie informacion los iconos.

```js
const elemento = document.querySelector('.contenido-texto');

document.querySelector('#btn-copy').addEventListener('click',()=>{

    document.querySelector('.mensaje-copy').classList.add('show');
    copyToClipBoard(elemento);

    setTimeout(()=>{
        document.querySelector('.mensaje-copy').classList.remove('show');
    },1300);
})

function copyToClipBoard(elemento){
    const inputOculto = document.createElement('textarea');
    console.log(inputOculto);
    
    inputOculto.value = elemento.innerText;

    document.body.appendChild(inputOculto);

    inputOculto.select();

    document.execCommand('copy');

    document.body.removeChild(inputOculto);

   
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Kufam', cursive;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #f2f0f5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h1{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contenedor-principal{
    text-align: center;
}

.contenido-texto{
    margin: auto;
    background: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.contenedo-btnCopy{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.contenedo-btnCopy button{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.mensaje-copy{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.show{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .6s;
}
img{
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Copiando al portapapeles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kufam:wght@400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor-principal">
        <h1>¡Copiando contenido al portapapeles con JS</h1>
        <div class="contenido-texto">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <i class="far fa-copy"></i> <!---QUISIERA COPIAR EN TEXTO ESTE ICONO!!-->
        </div>
        <div class="contenedo-btnCopy">
            <button id="btn-copy">
                
                <i class="far fa-copy"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="mensaje-copy">
            <p>¡Copiado al portapapeles!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hasta donde se, puedes copiar emojis en lugar de iconos generados por font-awesome, pero con iconos no creo que sea posible... Como esperas que sea el resultado del ícono que copiarás?...

Comment: De pronto añadiéndole algún titulo se podría? de esta forma: `<i class="far fa-copy title="Boton de copiar"></i>`

Comment: No veo un textarea en tu código

Comment: Creo un textarea para que se me copie ahi los datos y luego ocultarlo, pero los datos en si los tengo en el `<div class="contenido-texto">`